# OpenCV Laplacian output in C++ excludes negative values, but not in Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Performing the same Laplacian operation in `C++` and `Python` appears to produce different results.  Notably, the `C++` variant does not report negative slopes in the result matrix.

I am using (C++):

```
Laplacian(img.clone(), img, CV_16S, 1, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

and (Python):

```
img = cv2.Laplacian(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_16S, ksize=1, scale=1, delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

By processing the C++ data into a more friendly text format:

```
outfile.open("cpp.csv");
outfile.close();
for (size_t i = 0; i < img.size().width; i++) {
    outfile.open("cpp.csv", std::ios_base::app);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < img.size().height; j++) {
        outfile << (int16_t)img.at<uchar>(j, i);
        if (j < img.size().height - 1) {
            outfile << ",";
        }
    }
    outfile << std::endl;
    outfile.close();
}
```

I can then compare the values with `Numpy`.

```
cpp = np.loadtxt("./cpp.csv", delimiter=',')
print("python lap min:", np.min(img))
print("c++    lap min:", np.min(cpp))
```

This output shows us that the CPP code is not recording negative values:

> ```
> python lap min: -133
> c++    lap min: 0.0
> ```

So what is happening here?  Surely I have made some sort of error, because there must be negative values in a Laplacian transformation somewhere if the image luminosity values are not static.

## Image Source

The source image for each test case is a 1920x1080 full color PNG image with distinct light and dark areas.  I'm using a photo of the moon.  The image is converted to CV_8UC1 prior to the Laplace transformation.

## Strict Typing

I have explicitly told `C++` to store data with the `int16_t` type, which is implicitly signed by default, rather than just an `int`.  This typing matches the output from the Laplacian storage matrix (`CV_16S`).  Adding an explicit "signed" to "int16_t" produces the same result.  My understanding is that the `at` function requires `uchar` typing similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303073/using-matati-j-in-opencv-for-a-2-d-mat-object).  **This is where I was wrong!!!**

## Version Note

Python OpenCV version: 4.1.1 (or 4.4.0, see edit section)

C++ OpenCV version: 3.4.1 (or 4.4.0, see edit section)

The documentation for these versions ([3.4.1](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6) and [4.1.1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6)) shows no appreciable difference between the two.

## Similar Questions

Laplacian variation between `C++` and `Python` appears common on SO, but nothing had anything useful for this.  I read:

- [Laplacian does not give desired output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919978/laplacian-does-not-give-desired-output)
- [OpenCV - laplacian different results in Python and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903243/opencv-laplacian-different-results-in-python-and-c)
- [opencv 2.4.0 laplacian different results depending on API used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331830/opencv-2-4-0-laplacian-different-results-depending-on-api-used)

## Edit - Upgrading C++ OpenCV lib

I built `OpenCV` v.4.4 from git, and compiled the `C++` version of the code with `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`.  The same error persists.  (`cv2.getBuildInformation()` says the Python is running 4.4 as well).

## Edit2 - context from a Git issue:

I found a similar issue on the github repo ([here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17131)) where the solution was storing the Laplacian result as a new `Mat`.  My original code uses `Laplacian(img.clone(), img, ...)` which should produce a "deep copy" of the `img` matrix in place, avoiding the problem reported by the OP.  I tested my code with a unique matrix anyway `Laplacian(outputimg, img, ...)` and saw no change in results.

## Edit3 - Generalizing the problem

I processed the original code, this time replacing the Laplacian filter with either a Sobel and a custom `filter2D` filter.  The same result is observed, `Python` produces good values while `C++` does not.

## Edit4 - Post-answer cleanup

Since this was a simple typing error, I have crossed out most of the extraneous information.  This leaves it my original attempts readable, but it makes it obvious that they were not useful in the end.

Comment: Have you tried using the same version of OpenCV for both languages? It's possible there was a bugfix to the C++ interface at some point to fix not having negative values...

Comment: @MattDMo I updated to v4.4 and have the same problem.

Comment: Your C++ implementation is calling `Mat.at<uchar>` but the data is not `uchar`, it is `int16_t`. I see you are casting it *afterwards* but it's already incorrectly interpreted at that point. You're basically only reading the first byte of the two byte value and interpreting it as an unsigned `uint8_t`, and then casting that value to an `int16_t` which won't change the value. So I believe you'll only see values in [0, 255], even though you should see values in [−32768, 32767]

Comment: @alkasm The ``int16_t`` helped.  I thought the ``uchar`` was the type of the values for my ``x`` and ``y`` coordinate.  You should add this as the answer.  You can also add it at: https://answers.opencv.org/question/231134/laplacian-output-in-c-excludes-negative-values-but-not-in-python/ for bonus points.

Comment: @WesH I just wasn't sure if it was your only issue/a complete answer as I wasn't able to validate it. However, I'm slightly leaning towards closing this question as a typo, since, even though the answer is potentially helpful, the question actually presumes a lot more is going on which is not relevant, and isn't likely to be found/useful for future readers.

Comment: @alkasm I am going to edit the question to reflect the typo.  Other folks encountering similar problems may not be aware that they need to check this typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ implementation is calling `Mat::at<uchar>` which means "interpret the data at this location as `uchar` (i.e. `uint8_t`)" but your data is of course `short` (i.e. `int16`), not `uchar`. From the [docs on `Mat::at`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726), note that they specify:

> If matrix is of type `CV_16S` then use `Mat.at<short>(y,x)`.